# Word addin not reading appSetting

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, app-config

I have built a simple word addin that interacts with a company intranet.

For some reason, I cant seem t get the addin to read appSettings from its config file.

Is there something fundamental that doesn't allow office addins to read config files like a normal .Net application?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the config file needs to be associated with the winword.exe executable.

So for app settings to be read by an addin, even though the call to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is in another dll, the setting must sit in winword.exe.config.

Comment: Did it work for you? I have a Excel addin but my .config file named is based on the addin name and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This thread helped me:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653444/visual-studio-sp1-or-specifically-vsto-sp1-issue-with-config-file-location

In particular, this solved the problem for me:

> You'll need to make the change in your
>   deployment project, not in the .vsto
>   or .manifest files. Specifically, you
>   need to change the string written in
>   the "Manifest" registry value. For
>   example, the walkthrough in this
>   article directs you to set the
>   "Manifest" value to
>   "[TARGETDIR]ExcelAddIn.vsto|vstolocal":
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx.
>   To satisfy the new URI scheme
>   requirement for Fast Path loading, you
>   actually need to set the value to
>   "file:///[TARGETDIR]ExcelAddIn.vsto|vstolocal".

Answer (score 1):

I have a word addin and my config is the same as the  dll for example somedAddin.dll.config

Comment: Can anybody explain why some users can get addin.dll.config to work, while others must use winword.exe.config? (I belong in the latter group.)

Comment: Update: The following thread helped me. I have posted an answer about this as well. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653444/visual-studio-sp1-or-specifically-vsto-sp1-issue-with-config-file-location